# How to enter GPON serial number in hexadecimal?

Tags: networking, home-networking, fiber

I am trying to setup a [TP-Link XZ000-G3](https://www.tp-link.com/in/service-provider/gpon/xz000-g3/v2/) GPON terminal (ONT/ONU). It needs the correct serial number to register to my fiber provider's OLT.

The OEM GPON S/N is in the format: `GPON0012ABCD` but TP-Link's web management interface requires it to be a 16-digit hexadecimal. If I convert the S/N from ASCII to hex it becomes 24 characters `47504f4e3030313241424344` which it will not accept.

I couldn't find any documentation or manuals for this device anywhere on the internet and it came with basic instructions on wiring and accessing web interface only. I tried connecting to it via telnet but without documentation and an ironically helpless `help` command it didn't help.

What I've tried so far:

- Tried entering the hex `3030313241424344` without the GPON part and it didn't register.
- Tried entering the first 16 digits of the S/N hex `47504f4e30303132` and it didn't register.
- Very interestingly and in desperation I tried entering the hex for GPON `47504f4e` together with the rest of the S/N as is `0012ABCD` and it registers for a few seconds before redoing the registration process again.

All ideas in troubleshooting appreciated!

**Update as of June 27 2023**

I purchased a new ONT-only model from the same manufacturer (Netlink ICT) as my current ONT/Router/AP combination box. Documentation is non existent for all these devices even though they support telnet interface with more low level customization. Netlink at least offers more configuration options in their web and telnet interface.

A few observations after consulting [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a01f/415c25a97ca584cd1362adaab07aba303c2a.pdf) illuminating paper regarding GPON activation process (credit to [Jeff](https://superuser.com/users/1486435/jeff-isaacs) in the comments).

To recap the activation process:

- State O1: Initial state
- State O2: Standby state
- State O3: Serial number state
- State O4: Ranging state
- State O5: Operation state

1. The S/N `GPON0012ABCD` in the format `47504f4e0012ABCD` is correct. Without the correct S/N neither ONT manages to get to State O5 (registered, authenticated).
2. I tried changing the S/N in my working OEM ONT to a different one and it does not register.
3. I tried changing the PLOAM password (sent in State O5) in the OEM ONT and it made no difference. It appears my ISP is not checking for PLOAM password.
4. As far as GPON setup is considered, the TP-Link ONT supports setting S/N and PLOAM password only. With both configured as per the OEM ONT, it manages to get to State O5 but goes back to State O2 after a few seconds.
5. The new Netlink ONT supports the same configuration parameters as above and additionally setting LOID username and password. From the OEM ONT's config dump these two values are left empty. This ONT also gets to State O5 and holds it for a few more seconds than TP-Link but eventually goes back to State O2.
6. There is tx/rx network activity happening right after reaching State O5 in both ONTs. As the issue is unlikely to be related to the PLOAM password, there is some other issue preventing the ONT from staying registered.
7. The new Netlink ONT has some additional options for configuring *OMCI OLT mode* with values such as *default, Huawei OLT, ZTE OLT, and custom*. No changes in the aforementioned behavior was observed when cycling through these parameters.

Currently at a loss as to what the OLT requires after ONT reaches State O5 so that it can hold the O5 state. I did see some debug options in the telnet interface so my next course of troubleshooting will be down that path as the logging from the web interface proved to be not useful.

Comment: No idea about GPON. However, tried simply adding zeroes in front of _0012ABCD__?

Comment: I am confused `0012ABCD` would already be considered to be a hexdecmial format.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks, I tried with both leading and trailing zeros. No luck!

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it's valid hexadecimal, TP-Link's web interface wouldn't accept anything other than valid hex and anything more/less than 16 digits. So far, the best outcome was from chaining hex `47504f4e` for GPON together with the rest of the S/N as is like so `47504f4e0012ABCD`. The ONT tries to register for 30s, stays registered for the next 6s, goes offline for the next 6s and the process repeats.

Comment: `47504f4e0012ABCD` is your correct serial number. At least according to [this thread](https://community.ui.com/questions/Unofficially-support-3rd-party-OLTs-ONT-Serial-Number-Configuration-Serial-Changing/989b2134-f3b4-498a-a76f-b50a199b752e?page=2) it is. If you can't get into the logs, [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a01f/415c25a97ca584cd1362adaab07aba303c2a.pdf) describing the ONU activation process could point you in the right direction.

Comment: Which service provider? AT&T, for instance, besides the ONT, requires VLAN 0 tagged packets and 802.1X EAP authentication. Maybe your ONT connection is online but subsequent authentication steps are failing?